# Revoke Gmail 'send as' permission?

Tags: gmail, permissions, alias

Gmail has this convenient way to 'send email as' another account, to make it appear like the email came from that account rather than the Gmail mailbox. A great way to hook up your domain to your Gmail but still rely on Gmail's great SMTP servers. To get this started, you have to send a verification/permission request email to the concerned email address. Nice and safe.

However, I have a question with regard to revoking this verification afterwards.

Say I no longer have access to the Gmail account that can send on behalf of my @mydomain email account (as I've previously verified that it could do this). Is there a way to revoke this permission? I realise I can delete the alias from the Gmail account, but what if I do not have access to the account, and can only access the @mydomain email address? Can I force Gmail to re-verify?

Comment: That's a good question, but I don't think what you're looking for is possible. Anybody can set up an email to send "as" whatever address they like. What Google's doing is just preventing the most egregious phishing from coming through _their_ servers.

Comment: Do you happen to have the original verification message? It looks like (in recent versions at least) it contains a link to reverse a verification.

Comment: Excellent! Works like a charm. I was asking this as a preventive measure, so I can now make sure to save the email when I get it. Do you want to submit that as an answer, @AlE., so I can accept it? EDIT: The difference from 'anyone' doing this is that they don't have Google's powerfull and well-renowned SMTP servers ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save the verification email you get when you originally set up the "send mail as". At the bottom of the message is a different link and text that says:

> If you accidentally clicked the link [to verify your address], but you do not want to allow [redacted]@gmail.com to send messages using your address, click this link to cancel this verification:

If you click this second link, the account will be removed as a "send as" option for that Gmail account.

Comment: I have verified that this link remains active even after several years of 'send as'-activity. Great!